# Прошу проверить regex и помочь с RewriteRule

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

В индекс Google попадают левые URL, например

```
https://site.ru/blog?page=183/about
https://site.ru/blog?page=183?page=81
```

Правильная ссылка: `https://site.ru/blog?page=183`

На самом сайте кривых ссылок не нашел, решил сделать 301-й редирект через htaccess конкретно для этого случая, чтобы вырезалось все после знаков / или ?. С regex никогда не дружил, но методом проб и ошибок получилось так: `(blog\?page=[0-9]+)[\/?].*`

Кому не сложно, проверьте пожалуйста, правильно или чего-то не учел? И помогите пожалуйста сделать RewriteCond и RewriteRule, боюсь напортачить.

Comment: Попробуйте `rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(page=[0-9]+)[/?].*` и сразу после этой строчки `rewriterule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: Вместо `[/?]` нужно же `[\/?]`? Экранировать?

Comment: Не нужно, здесь нет разделителей. Это не PHP / JavaScript. Добавьте мой код в свой .htaccess после `rewriteengine on`, очистите кэш браузера и посмотрите, какой будет результат.

Comment: Проверил. `https://site.ru/blog?page=183?page=81` направляет на `https://site.ru/index.php?page=183` вместо `https://site.ru/blog?page=183`

Comment: Извините, проблему решил, у меня выше было правила редиректа на index.php, переместил его ниже и все заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу после `rewriteengine on` добавьте

```
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(page=[0-9]+)[/?].*
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R=301]
```

Очистите кеш браузера, и всё должно заработать.

**Подробности**

- `rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(page=[0-9]+)[/?].*` - в самом начале строки запроса ищет `page=` и 1+ цифр (за которыми должен быть знак косой черты или вопроса), захватывая их в подмаску `%1`
- `rewriterule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R=301]` - "переписывает" адрес, подставляя текущий адрес (`$1`), удаляя предыдущую строку запроса (с помощью `?`) и добавляя только захваеченное выше значение, потом останавливает обработку правил (`L`) и делает  301-редирект.